# How to update a Google Chrome password?

Tags: chrome-for-android, password

Here at work we use a Wi-Fi connection that requires the user's sign-in before it can be used, with a username and a password. This password is changed every few days. After connecting, Chrome starts and directs me to the login page, auto-filled, with the stored credentials. On my laptop, as soon as I enter a password that's different than the stored, I'm prompted to update it, therefore being able to auto-fill the form until it's changed again. However, on my Android Phone, Google never prompts me to apply that update. I can't seem to find a way of updating the password auto-fill, other than deleting the credentials and then signing in again, at which point Chrome prompts me to save the credentials with the "fresh" password. Is there any easier way to this? Thank you all in advance.

Comment: One thing can be open desktop site from your mobile browser will do the thing if you're convenient with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can head to https://passwords.google.com/ to manage your passwords, including updating and deleting them, as well as changing password-related settings.